# How to search for text from back to front

Tags: microsoft-word, images, vba, find-and-replace

**Backstory:**  I am copying and pasting search results from a website into word.  the pasted text looks something like the image below:

[image]

**Goal:**  I only want two lines from each set of search results (depicted in green).  Everything else needs to be deleted.  (very tedious when you have hundreds of search results).  I want to define a string that starts with the first word in red and ends with the next thumbnail image.  I then want to delete that.

**the good news:**  the first word in red is always the same.   We'll call it "First".

**My Problem:**  because the number of search results will always vary, the only way I can think of defining a range that ends with a picture is to start from the end of the document and work up.  I want to start with the last picture

```
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count)
```

then search backwards from this picture for the text "First".  Once I find the first occurence of that word, I want to create a range using the last picture and that word so I can delete it.  I can't figure out how to do this.

**Progress thus far:**  Here is what I have so far:  as of now, it searches forward for the text "first".  How do I reverse this?

```
Sub Clear_Stuff()

    Dim blnFound As Boolean
    Dim Pic As Range
    Dim First As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range

    Dim LastPic As InlineShape
        Set LastPic = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'=====================================================================================
' Selects the last picture on the document, moves the selection to the right once,
' and sets variable Pic to that selection
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    LastPic.Select
        Selection.MoveRight wdWord
        Set Pic = Selection.Range
'======================================================================================
' searches for the text "First", moves the selection to the left once
' and sets variable First to that selection
' then it sets the range variable rngFound with Pic and First as its bounds
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="First", Forward:=False
        blnFound = Selection.Find.Execute
        If blnFound Then
            Selection.MoveLeft wdWord
            Set First = Selection.Range
            Set rngFound = ActiveDocument.Range(First.Start, Pic.Start)
        End If

'========================================================================
' Deletes the range
'------------------------------------------------------------------------
    rngFound.Select
        Selection.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I certainly hope this is clear.  I will be happy to add any clarification anyone might ask for.  I am a novice at VBA.  If I can get this to work on the last search result, I will then loop this macro to take care of the entire set of results.

thank you so much for any and all help!

Comment: Just to be clear:  I need this part of my code:   [selection.find.text = "first"] to somehow tell the macro to search backwards from the end of the document.  perhaps the solution is to tell the macro to look for the last occurrence of the word "First" in the entire document.  is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Code to demonstrate how to delete the last occurrence of a given string

```
Sub DeleteLastOccurence() 
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="Hello", Forward:=False
    If myRange.Find.Found = True Then myRange.Delete
End Sub
```

The key part is `Forward:=False` where we tell VBA to search backwards

#### Before | After

[image][image]

#### Used resources

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839118.aspx

---

#### Edit

This code snipped searches for the last picture. Then it goes backwards to search the first occurrence of your key word (*First* in this example). It then selects the range between your key word and the picture. You can do whatever you want with it like deleting.

```
Sub DeleteLastOccurence()

    Dim rngPicture  As Range
    Dim rngJunk     As Range

    Set rngPicture = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count).Range
    Set rngJunk = Range(0, rngPicture.Start)

    rngJunk.Find.Execute FindText:="First", Forward:=False

    If rngJunk.Find.Found = True Then Range(rngJunk.Start, rngPicture.Start).Select

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I have updated the macro in my original post.  I managed to incorporate your suggestion into my macro, but there is still a problem.  For some reason,  the code finds the second-to-last occurrence of "First".  As a result, the range that is selected for deletion includes a set of search results that I want to keep.  In other words, when I loop this, it deletes half of my wanted data.  Do you have any idea why this might be happening??

Comment: @Jamiho What should be done with unwanted junk *after* the last picture?

Comment: that will be deleted too.  when this macro is successful,  it will just leave me with the two lines I want from each set of search result - separated by a single blank line.  As of now, I  manually delete the unwanted junk that appears after the last picture, then I run the macro.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time!  your second snipped of code works great.  I just changed "rngPicture.start" to "rngPicture.end" so that it deletes the pictures too.  Other than that, it is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show you my finished product:

First, the macro deletes the first picture (at the top of the document).  This will ensure that an error occurs when my loop reaches the top of the document

then, it proceeds to do what you helped me with, and loops forever until the error occurs (i.e., it cannot find another image).  At that time, the macro ends.

```
Sub DeleteLastOccurence()

    On Error GoTo GetOut

    ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Delete

    Do
        Dim rngPicture  As Range
        Dim rngJunk As Range

        Set rngPicture = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count).Range
        Set rngJunk = ActiveDocument.Range(0, rngPicture.Start)

        rngJunk.Find.Execute FindText:="KeyWord", Forward:=False

        If rngJunk.Find.Found = True Then ActiveDocument.Range(rngJunk.Start, rngPicture.End).Select
            Selection.Delete

    Loop While 1 + 1 = 2


GetOut:

End Sub
```

I'm sure there is a better way to tell a loop to go on forever, other than "loop while 1+1=2. but I figured that would work.  lol.

thanks again!

Comment: Consider some changes: http://pastebin.com/WCzXxWc8#